# Why IsNewRow always returning false?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my case, I was adding new row by `currencymanager.AddNew();`.

Why `IsNewRow` always returning `false`?:

```
private void DGV_Students_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
   {
       if (DGV_Students.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "student_id")
       {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt = Verify.VerifyStudentID(DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "هذا الطالب مسجل مسبقا ..!!";
               MessageBox.Show("هذا الطالب مسجل مسبقا ..!!", "اضافة طالب جديد");
           }
           else if (DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value == DBNull.Value)
           {
               DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "لا ينبغي ترك حقل السجل المدني فارغاً..!!";
               MessageBox.Show("لا ينبغي ترك حقل السجل المدني فارغاً..!!", "اضافة طالب جديد");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the Cell Validation is complete by the time it hits `IsNewRow`

Comment: Quote from the MSDN article: "A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins."  The CellValidating event fires after data was entered.  So yes, it is guaranteed to be false.  It is not obvious why you'd want to do this.  DGV also allows editing cells in existing rows, you still want to validate that.

Answer (score 0):

The row is new only until it has not been input any value.
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :

> DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow Property
>   Gets a value indicating whether the row is the row for new records.
>    ...
>   Because the row for new records is in the Rows collection, use the IsNewRow 
>   property to determine whether a row is the row for new records or is a 
>   populated row.
>
> **A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins.**

Comment: thank you all ..
so :A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins.
but I still do not know how to do it just for the new row.

Answer (score 0):

`DGV_Students.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow`

would always be false because you are in event **CellValidated** and the row which you are evaluating as passed new state of DataRow states.